# I want to scroll only day hour and time using mobiscroll

Tags: jquery, datepicker, scroller, mobiscroll

I want to only scroll day hour min using jQuery library mobiscroll, please suggest any solution.

Only scrollmonth and hour using mobiscroll jQuery library.

For more clarification please see below screenshot:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please look at this article to see how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since [MobiScroll](https://mobiscroll.com/) this is a paid plugin, I couldn't test.

But just looking at [their examples](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/v3/datetime#demo=expanded&theme=ios), something like this should make the **hours, minutes and second** scroll... But not the date.

```
$(function () {

    var min = new Date();
    min.setHours(0);
    min.setMinutes(0);
    min.setSeconds(0);

    var max = new Date();
    max.setHours(23);
    max.setMinutes(59);
    max.setSeconds(59);

    $('#demo').mobiscroll().date({
      theme: 'ios',
      display: 'bottom',
      dateWheels: '|MM d yy| hhii A',
      dateFormat: 'mm/d/yy hh:ii A',
      minWidth: 100,
      min: min,
      max: max
    });

});
```

The trick certainly is to play with `min` and `max`.
Maing them today at `00:00:00` and today at `23:59:59`, the date sure will not scroll.

Now in your question title, you ask for **day, hour and "time"**...
And in the question, you ask for **month and hours**...
And in the image, you ask for **hours, minutes and AM/PM**.

So this is unclear....
I made it just for time, having a fixed date as today.
But anyway, I guess you can use the same logic if you wanted something different.